# Custom report in React.js with rich text

Tags: reactjs, report

I have a page of text with about 250 words. I want to read data from the server and fill in blank spots. It contains numbers and names in the middle of paragraphs. It's like a contract. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Nobody knows the answer?